# how to split certain rows from the column dynamiclly in VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I have a column with data that has a description and a ID code (bold Char) with it:

**BBA-34.009876**

The harmful impact of the typical American diet.

The number of Americans that recycle on a regular basis.

The amount of time students use on social media.

The average college debt of undergraduate and graduate students.

How many public schools have cut arts programs.

How often do high school athletes succeed in college programs.

How healthy is the average public school lunch.

The number of low socioeconomic students that fail state standardized testing.

**CCV-09.89765**

A beautiful summer morning in the woods.

A character from a movie, cartoon, or book.

The most frightening place on the planet.

A personality you would like to resemble.

The best place for a winter vacation.

A holiday celebration in a certain country.

The most interesting piece of art in the nearest museum.

Describe your favorite season.

**FFG-890.786543**

Your first day of school.

Your favorite cuisine.

The experience of parachute jumping.

The memory of people you met when you were a child.

Your ideal study partner.

Environmental degradation caused by human activity.

**R-34.896543**

The worst d255 34 your life.

The best place to do homework.

The experience of learning a foreign language.

Choosing a college and a future career.

Your favorite camping spot.

The data set above is an example and there could be 50-2000 description in between the ID codes.  My question is how do you just split the ID codes from the descriptions, which are in separate rows but in the same column, and paste just the ID codes in a separate column but within the same row?  This also has to be dynamic and not a static input. Also the ID codes do not have the same pattern every time.

here is the VBA code that I have been working with and yes this is a Unifier style code within VBA.

```
Sub Unifier()
    Dim cell As Range
    Dim x As Integer
    Dim x2 As Integer
    Dim s As String
    Dim e As String
    Dim e2 As String
    Dim e3 As String
    Dim e4 As String
    Dim e5 As String
    Dim e6 As String
    Dim e7 As String
    Dim form As String





    s = Sheets("CostOS").Range("L2").Value 'Pulls 0
    x = Sheets("CostOS").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row 'Task Code Count
    x2 = Sheets("CostOS").Range("C" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row 'Item Code
    x3 = Sheets("CostOS").Range("D" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row 'Item Description Count
    x4 = Sheets("CostOS").Range("G" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row 'UM Count
    x5 = Sheets("CostOS").Range("F" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row 'Unit Rate Count
    x6 = Sheets("CostOS").Range("E" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row 'Quantity Count
    x7 = Sheets("CostOS").Range("H" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row 'CBS Count
    e = Sheets("CostOS").Range("L2").Value 'Approved by
    e2 = Sheets("CostOS").Range("L3").Value 'Estimate Type
    e3 = Sheets("CostOS").Range("L4").Value 'Estimate Number
    e4 = Sheets("CostOS").Range("L5").Value 'Estimator
    e5 = Sheets("CostOS").Range("L6").Value 'Approval Date
    e6 = Sheets("CostOS").Range("L7").Value 'Project Number
    e7 = Sheets("CostOS").Range("L8").Value 'Effective Date
    e8 = Sheets("CostOS").Range("V4").Value 'Task Code Prefix

    **'ID Code
    Sheets("CostOS").Range("D2:D" & x).Select
    Set cell = Sheets("CostOS").Range("A2:A" & x)
    For Each cell In cell
          If cell.Value = " " Then
             cell.Offset(0, 3).Value = Range("D2:D" & x)
          End If      
    Next**
    'Task Code, Prefix & H or D logic
    Sheets("CostOS").Range("A2:A" & x).Copy
    Sheets("EST template").Range("C3").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
    'H or D
    For Each cell In Sheets("EST template").Range("C3:C" & x)
        If cell.Value = "" Then
            cell.Offset(0, -2).Value = "H"
        Else
            cell.Offset(0, -2).Value = "D"
        End If
    Next
    Sheets("CostOS").Range("M3").Select 'Filldown Task Prefix
    Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("M3:M" & x7), Type:=xlFillDefault
    For Each cell In Sheets("EST template").Range("M3:Q" & x7)
    Next
    Sheets("CostOS").Range("N2").Select 'Filldown Milepost Prefix
    Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("N2:N" & x7), Type:=xlFillDefault
    For Each cell In Sheets("EST template").Range("N2:Q" & x7)
    Next
    Sheets("CostOS").Range("O2").Select 'Filldown Milepost Number
    Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("O2:O" & x7), Type:=xlFillDefault
    For Each cell In Sheets("EST template").Range("O2:O" & x7)
    Next
    'CBS & Approval Date
    Sheets("CostOS").Range("Q3").Select 'Removes end of CBS code
    Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("Q3:Q" & x7), Type:=xlFillDefault
    Sheets("CostOS").Range("T3").Select 'Fills down the vlookup
    Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("T3:T" & x7), Type:=xlFillDefault
    Sheets("CostOS").Range("T2:T" & x).Copy
    Sheets("EST template").Range("N3").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
    For Each cell In Sheets("EST template").Range("N3:N" & x)
        If cell.Text = "" Then
            cell.Value = e5
        End If    
    Next
    'Item Code
    Sheets("CostOS").Range("C2:C" & x).Copy
    Sheets("EST template").Range("G3").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
    For Each cell In Sheets("EST template").Range("G3:G" & x2)

    Next
     'Estimate number
    Set cell = Sheets("EST template").Range("A3:A" & x)
    For Each cell In cell
        If cell.Value <> "D" Then
             cell.Offset(0, 6).Value = e3
        End If
    Next
    'Effective Date
    Set cell = Sheets("EST template").Range("A3:A" & x)
    For Each cell In cell
        If cell.Value <> "D" Then
            cell.Offset(0, 8).Value = e7
        End If
    Next
    'Task Code Prefix
    Set cell = Sheets("EST template").Range("A3:A" & x)
    For Each cell In cell
        If cell.Value <> "D" Then
            cell.Offset(0, 9).Value = e8
        End If
    Next
    'Quantity & Estimator
    Sheets("CostOS").Range("E2:E" & x).Copy
    Sheets("EST template").Range("K3").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
    For Each cell In Sheets("EST template").Range("K3:K" & x6)
        If cell.Value = "" Then
            cell.Value = e4
        End If
    Next
    'Unit of Measure & Approved by
    Sheets("CostOS").Range("G2:G" & x4).Copy
    Sheets("EST template").Range("M3").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
    For Each cell In Sheets("EST template").Range("M3:M" & x4)
        If cell.Value = "" Then
            cell.Value = e
        End If
    Next
    'Unit Cost & Estimate Type
    Sheets("CostOS").Range("F2:F" & x5).Copy
    Sheets("EST template").Range("L3").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
    For Each cell In Sheets("EST template").Range("L3:L" & x5)
        If cell.Value = "" Then
            cell.Value = e2
        End If
    Next
    'Project Code
    For Each cell In Sheets("EST template").Range("C3:C" & x)
        If cell.Value = "" Then
            cell.Offset(0, -1).Value = e6
        Else
            cell.Offset(0, -1).Value = "Estimate Details"
        End If
    Next
    'Source
    For Each cell In Sheets("EST template").Range("C3:C" & x)
        If cell.Value = "" Then
            cell.Offset(0, 2).Value = "RailDOCS"
        Else
            cell.Offset(0, 2).Value = ""
        End If
    Next
    'Item Description
    Sheets("CostOS").Range("D3:D" & x3).Copy
    Sheets("EST template").Range("I4").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
    For Each cell In Sheets("EST template").Range("I4:I" & x3)

    Next
    'Short Description & Task Prefix
    Sheets("Est template").Select
    Sheets("Est template").Range("J4").Select
    With ActiveCell
        .Formula = "=LEFT(I4,50)"
    End With
    Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("J4:J" & x3), Type:=xlFillDefault
    For Each cell In Sheets("EST template").Range("J4:J" & x3)
    Next
    CutCopyMode = False
    End Sub
```

The bold portion is what I am haveing trouble with and everything else is working.

Comment: If you just want to know if a cell's text is bold use `Cell().Font.Bold`.

Comment: Sorry I meant for the text to be bold for clarification on what I need help with not to see if the text is bold within the data itself.

Comment: After you get it working you should post your code on [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/).  The experts there will analyze it and give you pointer on how to refine it.

Comment: Ok Thank you Thomas.  I will do that, the only problem with this code is to get it to work properly.  I have everything else in the code working except for the ID Code portion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### You can use the Like operator to test for a pattern

[image]

```
Sub TestLikePattern()
    Dim x As Long

    For x = 1 To Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        If Cells(x, 1) Like "*[A-Z][-]#*[.]#*" Then Cells(x, 2) = True
    Next

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like all ID Codes use hyphens. If none of the descriptions have them, you could use a test in InStr(). This function will return 0 if the hyphen does not exist (which would then be your description).

```
InStr(1, [Range Value], "-")
```

If this doesn't work, all the descriptions also seem to end with a period. A 2nd test could be:

```
If Right([Range Value], 1) = "." Then ...
```

EDIT: Adding how I'd use the test.

I would use the test in somewhat like this:

```
Sub SplitCodesFromDescriptions()
    Dim strCode As String
    Dim rngValues, rng As Range

    Set rngValues = Range("A1:A2500")

    For Each rng In rngValues

        If rng.Value = "" Then Exit Sub

        If InStr(1, rng.Value, "-") > 0 Then
            strCode = rng.Value
        Else
            rng.Offset(0, 1).Value = strCode
        End If

    Next
End Sub
```

*Note- I personally like defining the range. There can be issues where Excel thinks there is data in row 1 million.

Comment: Hi Kevin thank you for your comment.  Would I put that in place of  " cell = something"         like shown below:                          Sheets("CostOS").Range("D2:D" & x).Select
    Set cell = InStr(1, [Range Value], "-")
    For Each cell In cell
          If cell.Value = " " Then
             cell.Offset(0, 3).Value = Range("D2:D" & x)
          End If

Comment: Added to my answer how I'd handle it. It'd be better to normalize the data first and then go through more logic. I'm assuming there will be changes from Code Review. Also, you could just use this in your code and use Call to run it first.

Comment: Hi Kevin   Is there a way to paste those values in a separate sheet and then call them through the unifier code?

Comment: Are you meaning get Column A for Description and Column B for Codes in say, Sheet2, and also skipping rows with the code? Yes. I'd start with changing "For Each rng In rngValues" to "For i=1 to rngValues.Rows.Count". You can then use i for the row number in sheet2. Doing it this way, codes will need to be counted so you can offset the row in sheet2.